# Toggle classes on click with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, onclick, toggle

I have a page which contains some user entered text in one section and in another section a table of how many verbs, nouns etc are used in that text.  The table of verbs etc and the instances of those verbs in the text are styled in the same way via their class e.g. `<td style=""><span class="adverb">Adverb</span></td>` in the table and `<span class="adverb">here</span>` in the text.

I would like for a user to be able to click on the item in the table and for the appropriate class in the text and table to be toggled on and off.

For example, on the page sidebar the user sees a table which has in one column the words `verb`, `adverb`, `adjective` etc and these words are styled with a particular colour (`verb` is green, `adverb` is red, `adjective` is blue). In the main section of the page the user sees the text they have entered and each example of a grammatical type carries the same style (e.g. all words that are verbs are green, all adverbs are red).

When the user clicks on the word 'adverb' in the sidebar table I would like to toggle the `class="adverb"` to be present or not in both the table and the user entered text and therefore affect the styling that is applied.

Represetative markup for the table and text are below.  Any help much appreciated!

```html
    <table class="grammar table table-hover" data-toggle="table" data-sort-name="instance_use" data-sort-order="desc">
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th style="" data-field="grammar_type" tabindex="0">
                <div class="th-inner sortable both">Grammar Type</div>
                <div class="fht-cell"></div>
             </th>
             <th style="" data-field="instance_use" tabindex="0">
                <div class="th-inner sortable both desc">Instances of Use</div>
                <div class="fht-cell"></div>
             </th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
          <tr data-index="0">
             <td style=""><span class="adverb">Adverb</span></td>
             <td style="">2 </td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-index="1">
             <td style=""><span class="verb-present">Verb, present</span></td>
             <td style="">2 </td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-index="2">
             <td style=""><span class="determiner">Determiner</span></td>
             <td style="">2 </td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

Below is the markup where the user-entered content is rendered

```html
     <div id="story_text">
           <span style="white-space: pre-line">
           <span class="adverb">here</span> <span class="verb-present">is</span> <span class="determiner">a</span>
    <span class="adverb">another</span> <span class="verb-present">one</span> <span class="determiner">here </span><span class="adverb">multiple</span> <span class="verb-present">instances</span> <span class="determiner">word</span>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you elaborate or give an example if possible.

Comment: Hi - I have added some more information.  Hopefully this has made it a better question

Comment: Can there be multiple `verb, adverb, adjective`? if yes, then you must want to toggle the class of that particular word?

Comment: in the table there will only be one mention of the word `verb`, `adverb` etc.  However in the user entered text there could be any number of instances of verbs etc being used.  I've updated the example of user entered content to show how this might look

Comment: So after clicking on the particular `verb`,`adverb` etc. text of table, the class of that matched text entered in user's text should be toggled right?

Comment: yes.  So when user clicks on the word `adverb` in the table `class="adverb"` is toggled (both in the table `<td style=""><span class="adverb">Adverb</span></td>` and in the user entered text `<span class="adverb">here</span>`)

Comment: but be aware of situations like `<span class="verb-present">Verb, present</span>`  the class name is slightly different to the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I have created a solution that uses the `Element.classList.toggle` option documented at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

```
function toggleClass(obj) {
  const className = obj.classList[0];
  document.querySelectorAll('.' + className).forEach(element => {
    element.classList.toggle('blank');
  });
}
```

which is called on each item in the table `<td style=""><span class="adverb" onclick="toggleClass(this)">Adverb</span></td>`

This implements some CSS to override the existing styes

```
.blank {
  border: 0;
  color: black !important;
}
```

I was helped in this by @CertainPerformance in this question [How to correctly toggle classes using document.getElementsByClassName and Element.classList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51005330/how-to-correctly-toggle-classes-using-document-getelementsbyclassname-and-elemen/51005500#51005500)

Answer (score 0):

See, if this is what you are looking for

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.adverb').addClass('adverbFixed');
  $('.verb-present').addClass('verb-presentFixed');
  $('.determiner').addClass('determinerFixed');

  $('.adverbFixed').click(function() {
    $('.adverbFixed').toggleClass('adverb');
  });
  $('.verb-presentFixed').click(function() {
    $('.verb-presentFixed').toggleClass('verb-present');
  });
  $('.determinerFixed').click(function() {
    $('.determinerFixed').toggleClass('determiner');
  });
});
```

```css
.adverb {
  color: green;
}

.verb-present {
  color: red
}

.determiner {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="grammar table table-hover" data-toggle="table" data-sort-name="instance_use" data-sort-order="desc">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="" data-field="grammar_type" tabindex="0">
        <div class="th-inner sortable both">Grammar Type</div>
        <div class="fht-cell"></div>
      </th>
      <th style="" data-field="instance_use" tabindex="0">
        <div class="th-inner sortable both desc">Instances of Use</div>
        <div class="fht-cell"></div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-index="0">
      <td style=""><span class="adverb">Adverb</span></td>
      <td style="">2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-index="1">
      <td style=""><span class="verb-present">Verb, present</span></td>
      <td style="">2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-index="2">
      <td style=""><span class="determiner">Determiner</span></td>
      <td style="">2 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<div id="story_text">
  <span style="white-space: pre-line">
           <span class="adverb">here</span> <span class="verb-present">is</span> <span class="determiner">a</span>
  <span class="adverb">another</span> <span class="verb-present">one</span> <span class="determiner">here </span><span class="adverb">multiple</span> <span class="verb-present">instances</span> <span class="determiner">word</span>
</div>
```

Comment: many thanks @Rohit.007.  That has the desired functionality in your example, however there are a couple of issues.  1) It's not classes such as `red` that I want to toggle e.g. `toggleClass('red');`.  The class that I want to toggle is the class that is apparent on the item the user clicks on eg `<td style=""><span class="adverb">Adverb</span></td>` would toggle the `adverb` class.

Comment: 2) Do I have to hard code every rule ` $('.adverb')`, `$('.verb-present')` etc?  That could be a long list.  Is it possible to dynamically get the class value from the item being clicked on (like `var value = document.getElementById().value;` sort of thing) and then using that value in `$('.value').click(function() {
    $('.value').toggleClass('value');
  });`

Comment: Yes you can create a function() that will accept the class name dynamically and will do the stuffs you want

Comment: Now for your first query, Ideally you need a something to make toggle on the element. If we toggle the class itself, how the function will understand next time what to put back in place. if you are not having more item then these three, `adverb` and all then you do not need to add it dynamically every time. It will handle all the present elements.

Comment: Now I am toggling your classes.

Comment: Thanks Rohit.007 - i'll have a look at this in my code.  Re toggle - there lokos like an interesting toggle option in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Nice link, the same thing we are doing with addClass()

Comment: this is jquery, not js, you should mention that upfront ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is what you wanted, you cant customize the colors, of course.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("table .adverb").click(function() {
    toggleClass('adverb');
  });
  $("table .verb-present").click(function() {
    toggleClass('verb-present');
  });
  $("table .determiner").click(function() {
    toggleClass('determiner');
  });
});

function toggleClass(className){
    if ($("#story_text").hasClass(className)) {
      $("#story_text").removeClass(className);
    } else {
      $("#story_text").removeClass();
      $("#story_text").addClass(className);
    }
}
```

```css
.adverb .adverb, table .adverb {
  color: red;
}
.verb-present .verb-present, table .verb-present {
  color: green;
}
.determiner .determiner, table .determiner {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="grammar table table-hover" data-toggle="table" data-sort-name="instance_use" data-sort-order="desc">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="" data-field="grammar_type" tabindex="0">
        <div class="th-inner sortable both">Grammar Type</div>
        <div class="fht-cell"></div>
      </th>
      <th style="" data-field="instance_use" tabindex="0">
        <div class="th-inner sortable both desc">Instances of Use</div>
        <div class="fht-cell"></div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-index="0">
      <td style=""><span class="adverb">Adverb</span></td>
      <td style="">2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-index="1">
      <td style=""><span class="verb-present">Verb, present</span></td>
      <td style="">2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-index="2">
      <td style=""><span class="determiner">Determiner</span></td>
      <td style="">2 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="story_text">
  <span style="white-space: pre-line">
       <span class="adverb">here</span> <span class="verb-present">is</span> <span class="determiner">a</span>
  <span class="adverb">another</span> <span class="verb-present">one</span> <span class="determiner">here </span><span class="adverb">multiple</span> <span class="verb-present">instances</span> <span class="determiner">word</span>
</div>
```

Comment: this is jquery, not js, you should mention that upfront ;)