# How to correctly toggle classes using document.getElementsByClassName and Element.classList

Tags: javascript, toggle, getelementsbyclassname

I have a page where I want to be able to toggle classes on particular elements on or off.

In an attempt to do this I have written a function:

```
function toggleClass(obj) {
    alert(obj.className);
      Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(obj.className)).forEach(function(element) {
        element.classList.toggle(obj.className);
    });
}
```

which is called by items in a table e.g `<td style=""><span class="determiner" onclick="toggleClass(this)">Determiner</span></td>`.

This works fine when I first click the item, the alert is triggered and the class is removed.  When I click the same item in the table again to try and toggle/add the class the alert fires (empty because the class has been removed) but the class is not added.

Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong here?

```js
function toggleClass(obj) {
    alert(obj.className);
      Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(obj.className)).forEach(function(element) {
        element.classList.toggle(obj.className);
    });
}
```

```css
.determiner {
  /* color: rgb(248, 8, 8); */
  border: 1px solid rgb(248, 8, 8);
}

.preposition {
  color: rgb(40, 18, 236);
  /* border: 1px solid rgb(40, 18, 236); */
}

.verb-present {
  color: rgb(13, 146, 68);
  /* border: 3px solid rgb(13, 146, 68); */
}

span[class^='noun-'], span[class*=' noun-']{
  color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<table class="grammar table table-hover" data-toggle="table" data-sort-name="instance_use" data-sort-order="desc">
            <thead><tr><th style="" data-field="grammar_type" tabindex="0"><div class="th-inner sortable both">Grammar Type</div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th style="" data-field="instance_use" tabindex="0"><div class="th-inner sortable both desc">Instances of Use</div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th></tr></thead>
            <tbody><tr data-index="0"><td style=""><span class="adverb" onclick="toggleClass(this)">Adverb</span></td><td style="">2 </td></tr><tr data-index="1"><td style=""><span class="verb-present" onclick="toggleClass(this)">Verb, present</span></td><td style="">2 </td></tr><tr data-index="2"><td style=""><span class="determiner" onclick="toggleClass(this)">Determiner</span></td><td style="">2 </td></tr><tr data-index="3"><td style=""><span class="noun-sing-or-mass" onclick="toggleClass(this)">Noun, sing. or mass</span></td><td style="">1 </td></tr><tr data-index="4"><td style=""><span class="" onclick="toggleClass(this)">Preposition</span></td><td style="">1 </td></tr><tr data-index="5"><td style=""><span class="noun-plural" onclick="toggleClass(this)">Noun, plural</span></td><td style="">1 </td></tr><tr data-index="6"><td style=""><span class="comma" onclick="toggleClass(this)">Comma</span></td><td style="">1 </td></tr><tr data-index="7"><td style=""><span class="personal-pronoun" onclick="toggleClass(this)">Personal pronoun</span></td><td style="">1 </td></tr></tbody>
        </table>
        
<div id="story_text">
            <span style="white-space: pre-line">
            <span class="adverb">here</span> <span class="verb-present">is</span> <span class="determiner">a</span> <span class="noun-sing-or-mass">story</span> <span class="">with</span> <span class="determiner">no</span> <span class="noun-plural">commas</span><span class="comma">,</span> <span class="adverb">now</span> <span class="personal-pronoun">it</span> <span class="verb-present">does</span>
            </span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you keep referencing `obj.className`, but in the `forEach` loop, once the clicked element is iterated over, the `obj.className` becomes blank, so on further iterations (such as the "a" in `is a story`), the string passed to `element.classList.toggle` is blank.

Another problem is that when you try to click the element again, it has no existing class, so `obj.className` is empty - there's no class to toggle back on.

Instead of adding handlers in HTML attributes (which is as bad as `eval`), try iterating through all elements that need a handler *beforehand*, so you can build an array of elements for each `className` you want to be able to toggle.

A less elegant solution (that would require many fewer changes) would be to toggle a *different* class which overrides the `color` and `border` properties of the `determiner` and other classes:

```js
function toggleClass(obj) {
  const className = obj.classList[0];
  document.querySelectorAll('.' + className).forEach(element => {
    element.classList.toggle('blank');
  });
}
```

```css
.determiner {
  /* color: rgb(248, 8, 8); */
  border: 1px solid rgb(248, 8, 8);
}

.preposition {
  color: rgb(40, 18, 236);
  /* border: 1px solid rgb(40, 18, 236); */
}

.verb-present {
  color: rgb(13, 146, 68);
  /* border: 3px solid rgb(13, 146, 68); */
}

span[class^='noun-'],
span[class*=' noun-'] {
  color: #F00;
}

.blank {
  border: 0;
  color: black !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="grammar table table-hover" data-toggle="table" data-sort-name="instance_use" data-sort-order="desc">
            <thead><tr><th style="" data-field="grammar_type" tabindex="0"><div class="th-inner sortable both">Grammar Type</div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th style="" data-field="instance_use" tabindex="0"><div class="th-inner sortable both desc">Instances of Use</div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th></tr></thead>
            <tbody><tr data-index="0"><td style=""><span class="adverb" onclick="toggleClass(this)">Adverb</span></td><td style="">2 </td></tr><tr data-index="1"><td style=""><span class="verb-present" onclick="toggleClass(this)">Verb, present</span></td><td style="">2 </td></tr><tr data-index="2"><td style=""><span class="determiner" onclick="toggleClass(this)">Determiner</span></td><td style="">2 </td></tr><tr data-index="3"><td style=""><span class="noun-sing-or-mass" onclick="toggleClass(this)">Noun, sing. or mass</span></td><td style="">1 </td></tr><tr data-index="4"><td style=""><span class="" onclick="toggleClass(this)">Preposition</span></td><td style="">1 </td></tr><tr data-index="5"><td style=""><span class="noun-plural" onclick="toggleClass(this)">Noun, plural</span></td><td style="">1 </td></tr><tr data-index="6"><td style=""><span class="comma" onclick="toggleClass(this)">Comma</span></td><td style="">1 </td></tr><tr data-index="7"><td style=""><span class="personal-pronoun" onclick="toggleClass(this)">Personal pronoun</span></td><td style="">1 </td></tr></tbody>
        </table>
        
<div id="story_text">
            <span style="white-space: pre-line">
            <span class="adverb">here</span> <span class="verb-present">is</span> <span class="determiner">a</span> <span class="noun-sing-or-mass">story</span> <span class="">with</span> <span class="determiner">no</span> <span class="noun-plural">commas</span><span class="comma">,</span> <span class="adverb">now</span> <span class="personal-pronoun">it</span> <span class="verb-present">does</span>
            </span>
        </div>
```

Comment: That's awesome thanks @CertainPerformance.  I think at this time of night (for me) I'll go for the less elegant route for now and take a fresh look tomorrow morning :)

Comment: "*Instead of adding handlers in HTML attributes (which is as bad as eval)*" is somewhat overstated. Inline listeners are no more like using eval than is putting script in a script element.